# Animation Along a path with Auto Rotation based on the path in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have been trying to animate an image of a fly which moves in a path like the following image(which i have added for a clear idea) in **android version 2.2**

Well,this can be done in a very simple manner in the iphone as they have a property forsetting this auto rotation after the path is drawn using

```
animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
```

which i believe would rotate the object based on the path`

[image: Fly path]

I am able to animate ma fly through this path using the [nineoldandroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library using the methods

```
 path.moveTo(float x, float y);
 path.lineTo(float x, float y);
 path.curveTo(float c0X, float c0Y, float c1X, float c1Y, float x, float y);
```

Such that the curves are drawn through cubic B�zier curve.

Now what i have been trying is to implement something that would allow my fly to rotate itself along the path and i just cant seem to reach anywhere.

Please Help Me out with some ideas!!!  :( :(

Comment: and i have mentioned ANDROID vERSION 2.2 coz this app has to be made in 2.2 only,thus i hope it explains why i used NineoldAndroid Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to download the demo and the lib of [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) and [these 4 java files](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11125128/pathanimationangle.zip) if you want to use my solution**

That was easy, I modified the evaluator in the demo of nineoldandroids.

It's too much to post here:

Just to get the idea:

I extend the PathPoint with the field angle.
Then write all calculated Points in a stack (a simple float[][])

After the first calculation the angle can be calculated by the atan and the last 2 points in the stack.

If you don't want to use a stack you can modify the timeparam and look forward to where the next point will be drawn and calculate the angle out of these.

Just think about:
Do you first watch where you are walking to and then walk or do you just walk and then chose the angle for the destination. It's not neccessary since we have display densities that high and calculating the angle for each pixel.

Here's the PathEvaluator

```
public class PathEvaluatorAngle implements TypeEvaluator<PathPointAngle> {

private static final int POINT_COUNT = 5000;
private float[][] stack = new float[POINT_COUNT][2];
private int stackC = 0;

@Override
public PathPointAngle evaluate(float t, PathPointAngle startValue, PathPointAngle endValue) {
    float x, y;
    if (endValue.mOperation == PathPointAngle.CURVE) {
        float oneMinusT = 1 - t;
        x = oneMinusT * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * startValue.mX +
                3 * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * t * endValue.mControl0X +
                3 * oneMinusT * t * t * endValue.mControl1X +
                t * t * t * endValue.mX;
        y = oneMinusT * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * startValue.mY +
                3 * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * t * endValue.mControl0Y +
                3 * oneMinusT * t * t * endValue.mControl1Y +
                t * t * t * endValue.mY;
    } else if (endValue.mOperation == PathPointAngle.LINE) {
        x = startValue.mX + t * (endValue.mX - startValue.mX);
        y = startValue.mY + t * (endValue.mY - startValue.mY);
    } else {
        x = endValue.mX;
        y = endValue.mY;
    }

    stack[stackC][0] = x;
    stack[stackC][1] = y;

    double angle;

    if (stackC == 0){
        angle = 0;
    } else if (stackC >= POINT_COUNT){
        throw new IllegalStateException("set the stack POINT_COUNT higher!");
    } else {
        angle = Math.atan(
                (stack[stackC][1] - stack[stackC-1][1]) /
                (stack[stackC][0] - stack[stackC-1][0])     
                ) * 180d/Math.PI;
    }
    stackC++;
    return PathPointAngle.moveTo(x, y, angle);
}
```

}

Comment: The java files with the zip reference are no longer valid, is there any chance youll update it again so itll have the code of the 4 java files?

Answer (score 1):

**Please check the below link.Hope it will help.**

https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids

Comment: i had mentioned in my question,that i have used the nineoldandroid jar files too.....anyways...thanks